# Get all events handlers attached to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find all events handlers attached to #mySelect and if the event is created via jQuery I can get it , here alert(e) will show  only "change" without "click"

JavaScript :

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
    alert("changed");
})           
$.each($._data(  $("#mySelect")[0], "events" ), function(e) {
    alert(e);
})
```

Html :

```
<select id="mySelect" onclick="alert('hello')" >
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The short answer is that it's not possible to reliably determine all the listeners on an element just using javascript.

The long answer is that there is no standard mechanism to list all attached listeners. Some libraries keep a list of listeners that have been attached using the library, but don't necessarily know about other listeners. Listeners added in the markup or as element properties can be found by testing related element properties and attributes (somewhat tedious testing for *onclick*, *onchange*, *onblur*, etc. for each element). But it's impossible to find a listener added using *addEventListener* or *attachEvent* unless a reference has been kept somewhere and it's made available (see comment about libraries).

Also, there are "delegated" listeners that give the appearance of being attached to an element when in fact they are attached to a parent element.

Comment: If I can see all the events bound through the chrome inspector than certainly there should be some javascript way of doing the same right? Unless all the bound listeners are not visible in chrome either. Or chrome has some unexposed functionality that we do not have access to.

Comment: Cannot find a reliable way to do it, so this is probably the right answer. Basically attach dynamic events using some sort of wrapper/framework that keeps track of it and you are fine. In my case the framework that should be doing that is bugging out :) Really annoying to debug since you cannot inspect it by simply looking at properties.

Answer (score 15):

```
$( '#mySelect' ).bind( {
    'change': function( event ) {

    },
    'click': function( event ) {

    }
});


$.each($._data(  $("#mySelect")[0], "events" ), function(e) {
    alert(e);
});
```

Comment: You, sir, are a savior. I have been searching for something like this for hours now, inside and outside Stack Overflow, and no one had given a proper answer thus far. Your answer, however, did the trick.

Comment: this code only works for jQuery v1.*.*,  but not for v2.*.*

Comment: I'm voting this down, because in general use in any language, you are not supposed to access methods that start with and underscore. These are private class methods.

Comment: @CrazyMerlin "in any language"???  Plus there are ways of making methods *truly* private; one should *not* have to rely on prepending the method name with an underscore as a convention to indicate that a method should merely be *considered* private.  If it's publicly accessible it is in essence part of the interface and the developers should have been more careful to not let the abstraction leak.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty This is JavaScript, there are no real private methods, so the use of an underscore is the developers way of telling someone using the library not to use the method. Private methods don't have to care about public consumption so will change without telling you...hence, don't use them!

Comment: @CrazyMerlin I'm well aware it's Javascript, but I'm also well aware that you actually *can* create private methods in Javascript

Comment: @GeorgeJempty If you're talking about exporting, or prototyping, or closures, then you're not talking about real private methods, you're talking about scope emulation. JavaScript is not a programming language, so it was never designed with true private scope in mind.

Comment: @CrazyMerlin stop being a pedant and just admit there are ways to not have to expose non public functionality in javascript instead of the inane convention of pretending names with an underscore

Answer (score -1):

In addition for events attached inline you can try this:

```
alert(document.getElementById('mySelect').getAttribute('onclick'));
```

Comment: doesn't work if the event handler is attached dynamically.