# Is there a way to hook a certain jquery function, on any element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried searching for a way to hook the mouseleave event on any document and could accomplish this snippet:

```
let hook = $(this).mouseleave(() => {
    alert('mouseleave')
});
$(this).mouseleave = (...args) => (alert('mouseleave'));
```

It successfully registers any mouseleave events, but my goal is to replace the existing mouseleave function of a page to my function of choice. The question is: Is there a way to capture the existing mouseleave events globally to replace them with my own function?

Comment: Are you looking to *remove* the existing events and then add your own, or add your own as a wrapper?  (ie your event calls the original event)

Comment: Is it a third-party page or your own? If the existing event is fired in bubbling mode, you could add another listener in capture mode, and if the existing listener is not needed, stop the propagation in your handler.

Comment: Looks like you're asking: how do I find existing events in order to replace them - short answer: you can't

Comment: A third party page. I am looking to remove the existing events and add my own.

Comment: related question, *possible* duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18116524/2181514

Answer (score 0):

> replace the existing mouseleave
>
> existing mouseleave events globally

you can remove any event from a node using `.off()`, eg

```
$("*").off("mouseleave");
```

to remove all mouseleave events from all elements

More info: https://api.jquery.com/off/