# Paste event listener not working for Gmail body and Facebook Messenger Chat

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I'm creating a browser extension that will strip UTM metrics from URLs to make them cleaner to share. I can do this pretty reliably through a popup click, but I'm trying to add a listener so it will fire automatically when it detects a URL being pasted.

Because navigator.clipboard is a huge pain to work with and requires permissions for every site, I'm using

`document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, trimmed_url)`

to paste my formatted URL link.

This works just fine for search bars, subject lines, and conversation boxes, but when I try and paste in a Gmail body or a FB Chat window, I get the original unaltered url, followed immediately by the trimmer_url

Example:

https://www.theonion.com/san-francisco-realtor-shows-couple-earning-under-6-figu-1850289467?utm_campaign=The%20Onion&utm_content=1681314305&utm_medium=SocialMarketing&utm_source=facebook&fbclid=IwAR0FY7EO505rXu1eyGNYzN_tTkuUfyNl6EKqvuf_r-_N5fBfq4F1Sdisb8A

Goes to -->

https://www.theonion.com/san-francisco-realtor-shows-couple-earning-under-6-figu-1850289467?utm_campaign=The%20Onion&utm_content=1681314305&utm_medium=SocialMarketing&utm_source=facebook&fbclid=IwAR0FY7EO505rXu1eyGNYzN_tTkuUfyNl6EKqvuf_r-_N5fBfq4F1Sdisb8Ahttps://www.theonion.com/san-francisco-realtor-shows-couple-earning-under-6-figu-1850289467

Code:

```
function pasteClipboard(){

    window.addEventListener("paste", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        let paste = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData("text/plain");
        let trimmed = trimURL(paste);


        setTimeout(function() {
            document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, trimmed);
            }, 50);


    });
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I can see in the console logs that trimURL is working correctly and I'm getting the same behavior for both Gmail Bodys and FB Chat as I'm making changes, so I'm assuming there's something specific to those elements that is getting in the way.

div classes for FB Chat and Gmail body

FB:

```
<div aria-describedby=":r74:" aria-label="Message" class="xzsf02u x1a2a7pz x1n2onr6 x14wi4xw x1iyjqo2 x1gh3ibb xisnujt xeuugli x1odjw0f notranslate" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="true" tabindex="0" data-lexical-editor="true" style="user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word;"><p class="xat24cr xdj266r"><br></p></div>
```

Gmail

```
<div id=":yv" class="Am Al editable LW-avf tS-tW" hidefocus="true" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr; min-height: 226px;" spellcheck="false" aria-owns=":11o" aria-controls=":11o"><br></div>
```

I'm trying to get it to so just the updated url is being pasted into the chat body.

Comment: They probably have their own paste event handlers, which will run anyway, regardless of preventDefault.

Comment: Do you know of any way for me to detect whether a site has it's own paste event handler so I can disable my code in that case?

Comment: Not really.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116163/get-all-events-handlers-attached-to-an-element - some developer tools/consoles have a function getEventListeners but it’s not available in plain javascript.  See also https://www.sqlpac.com/en/documents/javascript-listing-active-event-listeners.html